# Error duringSql server to MYSQL database migration through MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, database-migration

Sql server databse is migrating to Mysql through mysql workbench. I tested both connectiona are working.
I follow migration wizard step by step, 
i got some warnings at Manual Editing(Foriegnkey related), but any how i did continue.

Main issue is at Create Target Results: i am getting error

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes. SQL Error:
>       1071 (i solved it by editing VARCHAR(255) to VARCHAR(191))
>
> ERROR: Error executing 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `IPHR_Main`.`PHRRecommendationEngine_Rule_Filter_Mapping` (
>         `RuleId` BIGINT NOT NULL,
>         `FilterId` BIGINT NOT NULL,
>         PRIMARY KEY (`RuleId`, `FilterId`),
>         CONSTRAINT `FK_PHRRecommendationEngine_Rule_Filter_Mapping_PHRRecommendati127`
>           FOREIGN KEY (`FilterId`)
>           REFERENCES `IPHR_Main`.`PHRRecommendationEngine_Filter` (`FilterId`)
>           ON DELETE NO ACTION
>           ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
>         CONSTRAINT `FK_PHRRecommendationEngine_Rule_Filter_Mapping_PHRRecommendati128`
>           FOREIGN KEY (`RuleId`)
>           REFERENCES `IPHR_Main`.`PHRRecommendationEngine_Rule` (`RuleId`)
>           ON DELETE NO ACTION
>           ON UPDATE NO ACTION)'
>       Identifier name 'FK_PHRRecommendationEngine_Rule_Filter_Mapping_PHRRecommendati127' is too long.
>       SQL Error: 1059

So can anyone help solving the above error? I know identifier length in sql server is 128 chars whereas in Mysql it is 64 chars. so how can i get rid of this errors with out changing the names.

Thanks!!

Comment: So essentially your question is how can you make 128 characters fit into 64 characters without changing the text. Ummm.....

Comment: Yes! @SeanLange Lange

Comment: Well that isn't possible. Seriously think about what you are asking. The limitation in mysql is 64 characters, you have identifiers that are longer than that. It is not possible to make 128 characters fit into 64 characters. It doesn't make any sense. You MUST change the names to meet the length limitations of the new DBMS you are migrating to. There is no work around here.

Comment: Look at your example foreign key. The name is 65 characters. If the text doesn't change the length isn't going to be reduced to 64. The ONLY way you can make it be 64 characters or less is by removing some characters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the request is impossible.

Comment: Well, i am not a pro in DB.  That's what i thought initially. But, Just in case looking for an expert suggestion/advise. **Thanks** for your help. :)